# How can I concatenate a whole string, to create URL, links and append to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like this:

```
"USA_legacy"\n"flow_folder"\n"pre_fix"\n\n'
```

All of these IDs are stored in a list named `'mylist'` (very creative).  I'm trying to concatenate these IDs into a string, which is a URL for an intranet that I'm working with.  I thought it would be something like this:

```
urllist = []
for line in mylist:
    line = 'https://internal.corp.com/admin/'+line+'&num_runs=100&root='
    urllist.append(line)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `mylist` looks like (and is acting like) a string. Try `for line in mylist.splitlines()`

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run: `mylist` is undefined.  The initial "list" you posted is not a Python `list`.  Since we don't know *exactly* what you have to start, we have a hard time helping  you.

Comment: your `list` looks like a string, and not a valid one either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for _id in (it.strip('"') for it in mylist.split('\n') if it):
    line = 'https://internal.corp.com/admin/={}&num_runs=100&root='.format(_id)
    urllist.append(line)
```

Well if you need the quotes around the ids then do not strip them

or in one line:

```
urllist = ['https://internal.corp.com/admin/={}&num_runs=100&root='.format(_id.strip('"')) 
           for _id in mylist.split('\n') if _id]
```

Comment: Tomasz, this will work!  I was getting and extra ", so, I stripped it out in the preceding step.  one quick question for you...What does the {} do?  I guess it's the placeholder for the variable, right.

Comment: You are correct it is a placeholder for a variable, using format method on a string is the idiomatic way of inserting values into strings in python